# Non-standard Queuing Theory problem (Modified M/M/1)

Tags: probability, markov-chains, queueing-theory

Haven't see anything like it in queueing theory, the problem appears to be M/M/1 but with a twist?

Description:
The server starts serving calls only when the number of customers in the system becomes 3. In all other cases, the system behaves like a typical M/M/1 queue.

When the server starts serving calls, it serves them normally, even if their number is less than 3. However, if all calls are served and the system becomes empty (n = 0), the server will again start serving calls only when their number in the system becomes 3.

I can't even create a state diagram?

Comment: There is no actual question there, but the key is that you go from $0$ to $3$ with a suitable gamma distribution

Comment: You are correct, i should had formulated my question better. What's the state diagram in the above question? How i can derive it?

Comment: Your choice.  There is no $0\curvearrowright1$ or  $1\curvearrowright2$ or $2\curvearrowright 3$ transition.  So either have  a $0\curvearrowright3$ jump with a gamma distribution for the times or have a couple of new states $1^*$ and $2^*$ with  $0\curvearrowright1^*$ and   $1^*\curvearrowright2^*$ and $2^*\curvearrowright 3$ with usual exponential distributions

Answer (score 1):

To model this as a CTMC the simplest way would be to add states $1^*$ and $2^*$ as Henry mentioned in the comments. So the state space would be $S=\{0,1^*,2^*,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and the transitions similar to a regular $M/M/1$ queue, with generator matrix as
$$
Q=\begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda & \lambda & 0&0&0&0&0\\
0&-\lambda &\lambda & 0&0&0&0\\
0&0&-\lambda&0&0&\lambda&0\\
\mu &0&0&-(\lambda+\mu) & \lambda & 0&0\\
0&0&0&\mu&-(\lambda+\mu)&\lambda&0\\
0&0&0&0&\mu&-(\lambda+\mu)&\lambda&\cdots
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Solving the balance equations
$$
\sum_{i\in A,j\in S\setminus A}q_{ij}\pi_{i} = \sum_{i\in S\setminus A,j\in S}q_{ij}\pi_i
$$
for the sequence of subsets of the state space $A=\{0\}, \{0,1^*\}, \{0,1^*,2^*\},\ldots\ $ subject to the condition $\sum_{i\in S}\pi_i =1$ yields the stationary distribution
\begin{align}
\pi_0&=\frac{\mu  (\mu -\lambda )}{2 \lambda ^2+\mu ^2}\\
\pi_{1^*} &= \frac{\lambda ^2 (\mu -\lambda )}{\mu(2 \lambda ^2  +\mu ^2)}\\
\pi_{2^*} &= \frac{\lambda ^2 (\mu -\lambda )}{\mu(2 \lambda ^2  +\mu ^2)}\\
\pi_1 &= \frac{\lambda  (\mu -\lambda )}{2 \lambda ^2+\mu ^2}\\
\pi_2 &= \frac{\lambda ^2 (\mu -\lambda ) (\lambda +\mu )}{\mu ^2 \left(2 \lambda ^2+\mu ^2\right)}\\
\pi_n &= \frac{\lambda^n(\mu -\lambda ) (\lambda +2 \mu )}{\mu^n(2 \lambda ^2+\mu ^2)},\ n\geqslant 3.
\end{align}

Comment: How is P_0 derived?

Comment: By expressing all $\pi_i$ in terms of $\pi_0$ and substituting into $\sum_{i\in S}\pi_i = 1$, then solving for $\pi_0$. Also note that we are assuming $\lambda<\mu$ (which is a necessary and sufficient condition for this type of process to have a stationary distribution) so that $\mu-\lambda>0$ and the $\pi_i$ are positive.